# Specify my dataset as working dataset

Tags: r, dataset

I am a newbie to R.

I can successfully load my dataset into R-Studio, and I can see my dataset in the workspace. 
When I run the command `summary(mydataset)`, I get the expected summary of all my variables.

However, when I run

```
data(mydataset)
```

I get the following warning message:

```
In data(mydataset) : data set ‘mydataset’ not found
```

I need to run the `data()` command as recommended in the `fitLogRegModel()` command, which is part of the [PredictABEL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PredictABEL/index.html) package.

Does anybody have a hint on how I can specify `mydataset` as working dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the `data` command.  You can just pass your data to the function

```
riskmodel <- fitLogRegModel(data=mydataset, cOutcome=2, 
     cNonGenPreds=3:10, cNonGenPredsCat=6:8, 
     cGenPreds=c(11, 13:16), cGenPredsCat=0)
```

The example uses `data(ExampleData)` so that it can make data that is in the package available to you.  Since you already have your data, you don't need to load it.

Comment: GSee; Thank you, that helps. I was able to work on my dataset.

Comment: GSee; Is there any way I can use the column header instead of specifying the column numbers. For instance: cOutcome=myoutcome, instead of cOutcome=2? That would help. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I tried for hours. The best solution I was able to find was to enter command attach(mydataset). After that, I was able to enter commands mean(age) and so on. However, I understand there are caveats regarding the attach commands, and I was wondering if there are safer and more efficient ways to do that.

Comment: If `mydataset` is a `data.frame`, you can subset like this `mydataset[["myoutcome"]]`

Comment: Thank you. mydataset$myoutcome seems also to work. Sorry for such basic questions, but the learning curve for R seems steep to me despite the abundant introductory literature available. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, although it has its drawbacks, is to use `attach(mydataset)`. You can then refer to variables without a `mydatdataset$` prefix. The main drawback, as far as I know (although I'd welcome the views of more expert R users) is that if you modify a variable after attaching, it is then not part of the dataset. This can cause confusion and lead to "gotchas". In any case, many expert R users counsel against the use of `attach`.

Comment: I would say that a bigger drawback is that you increase the risk of conflicts/masking.  Consider if you have a vector in the global environment with the same name as a column in the attached data set, or you have 2 data sets attached with 1 or more columns having the same name.  It is easy to get errors and warnings that are not obvious (lengths don't match), or worse yet, no error or warning but a result that is meaningless but looks reasonable.  Best is to use the data argument in functions, the `with` or `within` functions are next best.

Comment: Peter; thank you for sharing this alternative and its drawbacks. I appreciated it.